# Is it possible to skip the secure delete step when installing Debian with LUKS full-disk encryption?

Tags: debian, luks

I'm installing Debian using LUKS full-disk encryption onto brand new 500GB hard drives. Currently it's taking ~24 hours to prep the drive for installation by securely deleting the drive. Since it's a brand new drive that's never been used before, is it possible to configure the install process to skip the secure delete step so it doesn't take so long to install?

I'm using a preseed file to drive the install, so if such configurations exist it'd be great to know what the specific preseed options are.

Answer (score 0):

Possible --sure  BUT that makes it less secure, while not widely known in the general public there are often loggers and / or traces of the initial mbr and such in brand new drives that are NOT wiped by the default formating (which is more like a etch-a-sketch than a proper format as it merely wipes out the "journal" not the wiping the signatures and inode redirects at the lower level... If this is merely for luks experience and not truly to protect highly sensitive materials skipping it is fine..  Just remember for any proper /secure install skipping it  invites vulnerabilities that a  decently skilled investigator / attacker can with much more ease exploit.   also sidenote seeing as its a NEW drive...  Get the full extent of the drive put at your disposal -- the default formatting uses more overhead than most installs (especially luks ones) need to make them universally useable.

EDIT: Updated process:

1. DON'T wipe the drive use the default format done at time of luksDevice Format
2. Proceed with install
3. have a admittedly more vulnerable but useable Luks'd install.

Comment: This answers the 'is it possible' part, but not the actual 'how to' section of the question. Can you update to include that information to create a full answer? Otherwise this is basically just a security warning...

Answer (score 0):

Since, you are using the preseed file, take a look at this:

https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/preseeding-full-disk-encryption

The post suggested, that we have to edit the file `crypto-base.sh` to skip the secure deletion process

```
d-i partman/early_command \
       string sed -i.bak 's/-f $id\/skip_erase/-d $id/g'
/lib/partman/lib/crypto-base.sh
```

A brand new hard doesn't need to go through this process, so if somebody told you that you must do this process to increase security, they actually don't know what they are talking about.

NEW: There are new syntax to skip disk wipe without going through all of the above:

```
  echo "d-i partman-crypto/passphrase string ${LUKS_PASS}"
  echo "d-i partman-crypto/passphrase-again string ${LUKS_PASS}"
  echo "d-i partman-crypto/weak_passphrase boolean true"
  echo "d-i partman-crypto/confirm boolean true"
  echo "# When disk encryption is enabled, skip wiping the partitions beforehand."
  echo "d-i partman-auto-crypto/erase_disks boolean false"
```